# array layout in the memory

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, visual-c++, memory-management, int

I would like to know why in the following code the difference between pointers 
aptr and amemTab is not equal the size of allocated array (10*sizeof(A)) but 64 bytes (sizeof(A) is 4).

in the debug mode:

aptr 0x00395e38

amemTab 0x00395e78

Win XP Home Edition,MSVS2010,x86 Intel 1.86

I guess it has something to do with padding? (I haven't deleted the code of base and derived class, as I want to show exactly what I am testing, but it is redundant here,
I am talking only about two lines:

```
A * aptr=static_cast<A*>(amem);
void * amemTab= operator new[](10*sizeof(A));
```

my full example:

```
// exercise
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <algorithm>

void func(const int &i){printf("%d\n",i);}

class A{
public:
    int i;
};
class B{
public:
    int i;
private:
    int j;
};
class base{
public: 
    void f(void){printf("base f not virtual\n");}
    virtual void g(void){printf("base g virtual\n");}
    void h(void){printf("base h not virtual\n\n");}
    int i_;
    base():i_(123){}
    base(int):i_(12345){}
};
class derived:public base{
public: 
    void f(void){printf("derived f not virtual\n");}
    virtual void g(void){printf("derived g virtual\n");}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int ij;
    A a;/*a.i is not initialized*/
    A * aprimprim=new A;/*i is not initialized (but ctor has been called)*/
    A aprim=A();/*aprim.i is 0 initialized as it is public variable 
                and A has only public part (A is POD type) and () is written*/
    A * ap=new A();/*int is 0 initialized*/
    B b;/*b.i is not initialized and b.j is not initialized*/
    B bprim=B();/*bprim.i is not initialized and bprim.j is not initialized
                as A has public AND also private part*/
    B * bp=new B();/*ints are both 0 initialized*/

    void * amem= operator new (sizeof(A));/*uninitialized memory, only allocate*/
    A * aptr=static_cast<A*>(amem);//cast pointer to void to pointer to A

    void * amemTab= operator new[](10*sizeof(A));/*uninitialized memory, only 
                                            allocate for 10 objects of A size*/
    A * aptrtab=static_cast<A*>(amemTab);/*cast pointer to void to pointer to 
                                         A. now it is possible to iterate through
                                         this area of indexed memory:*/
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        new(&aptrtab[i])A();//initialize each A object 
    }
    int s=sizeof(A);
    /*------------------------------*/
    int myarray[5];/*ints are uninitialized*/
    *(1+myarray)=13;/*pointer addition is commutative*/
    2[myarray]=4;/*subscript operator is commutative*/

    std::for_each(myarray,myarray+5,func);

    /*---------------*/
    int *what_here=const_cast<int*>(myarray-6600);
    printf("what_here: %d\n",*what_here);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, nothing definite can be said about the relationship between pointers returned by two consecutive heap allocations. It would not be inconceivable for the allocator to return pointers from two completely different regions of memory (for example, it could use different sub-heaps depending on how many bytes are requested).

What is likely happening in your case is that:

1. your allocator manages memory in chunks larger than one byte;
2. the allocator uses a few bytes adjacent to the allocated memory for its internal data structures.

Both of these incur overheads.

Also, memory allocations have to satisfy certain alignment requirements. This can in general lead to further overheads.

Comment: true, I've totally forgotten that this is on the heap, I was thinking about stack, oh..  thanks!

Comment: @cf16: also be careful about making assumptions on the locations of local (stack-based) variables. There's nothing that says that the compiler has to lay out two local variables declared on adjacent lines of source also adjacent in memory on the stack. Non-optimized builds will often have this property, but not necessarily. And for optimized builds, all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

aptr and amemTab are the results of 2 separate allocations (one goes through new, the other new[])

Since your example is small, the heap is quite empty and they are allocated very near to one another, in your case, 64 bytes apart. However, nothing is stopping the allocation from being several megs away. That is completely up to Microsoft's implementation of HeapAlloc, where all new's, new[]'s, and malloc's eventually end up going.

If you take a look at what is between the 2 allocation in a debugger, you are very likely to see 0xAB repeated. This indicated "no man's land" on the heap. In higher addresses you are more likely to see 0xCD indicating that the heap memory has yet to be used.

On a completely unrelated note, you are treating the new and new[] operators a lot like a C-style malloc() in your example. I hope you know there are type-safe, and much more readable, ways of doing your allocation. For example:

```
A *amemTab = new A[10]; // Allocated an array of 10 A's.
```

Comment: and yes, ofcourse :p I have focused on operator new, as it doesn't call constructor - it is crucial to me in this exercise :p